Animated Style Interpolation Not Working in React Native Reanimated
I'm working on a React Native project where I want to create a wheel-like picker with items that fade in and out as they scroll into view. I'm using react-native-reanimated for the animations, but the opacity interpolation doesn't seem to be working as expected.
What I Have Tried:
Here is my component code:
import { StyleSheet, View, Modal } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import Text from "../atoms/Text";
import Animated, {
  Extrapolation,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Button from "../atoms/Button";
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { COLORS, DEVICE } from "../../common";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 60;
const ITEM_WIDTH = 100;
const WHEEL_HEIGHT = ITEM_HEIGHT * 5;

const WheelModal = () => {
  const { bottom } = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const eventY = useSharedValue(0);

  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
    eventY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
  });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const activeNumber = eventY.value / ITEM_HEIGHT;
    const inputRange = [
      (activeNumber - 2) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
      (activeNumber - 1) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
      activeNumber * ITEM_HEIGHT,
      (activeNumber + 1) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
      (activeNumber + 2) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    ];

    const opacity = interpolate(
      eventY.value,
      inputRange,
      [0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1],
      Extrapolation.CLAMP
    );

    return {
      opacity,
    };
  });

  const onSelect = () => {
    console.log("selected year", yearGenerator()[eventY.value / ITEM_HEIGHT]);
  };

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={true} animationType="fade">
      <View style={styles.titleBox}>
        <Text weight="bold" size="lg" tx="Choose the year" />
      </View>
      <LinearGradient
        locations={[0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1]}
        colors={[
          "rgba(256,256,256,.6)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.95)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,1)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.1)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.2)",
        ]}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
        <Animated.FlatList
          bounces={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          onScroll={scrollHandler}
          data={yearGenerator()}
          decelerationRate="normal"
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          snapToInterval={ITEM_HEIGHT}
          style={styles.flatList}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.animatedView, animatedStyle]}>
              <Text size="lg" weight="medium" text={item.toString()} />
            </Animated.View>
          )}
        />
        <View style={styles.borderView} />
      </LinearGradient>
      <Button
        onPress={onSelect}
        tx="Select"
        style={[styles.selectButton, { height: 45 + bottom }]}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  titleBox: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: DEVICE.height / 2 - WHEEL_HEIGHT / 2 - 49,
    alignSelf: "center",
    zIndex: 999,
  },
  flatList: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    height: WHEEL_HEIGHT,
  },
  flatListContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingVertical: ITEM_HEIGHT * 2,
  },
  animatedView: {
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  borderView: {
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    position: "absolute",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: COLORS.primary,
  },
  selectButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

const yearGenerator = () => {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const years = [];
  for (let i = 2015; i <= year; i++) {
    years.push(i);
  }
  return years;
};

export default WheelModal;



What I Expected:
I expect the opacity of the items to decrease as they move away from the center item, creating a fading effect.
What Actually Happens:
The opacity animation does not work, and all items have the same opacity regardless of their position in the list.
Additional Information:
React Native Version: 0.74.3
React Native Reanimated Version: 3.10.1
Screenshots:

Question:
What am I doing wrong in my animation code? How can I get the opacity interpolation to work correctly so that items fade in and out as they scroll into view?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Did you not get an error about hooks having to be at the top level? If you want to use hooks in renderItem then you have to make a separate component

there is no error I got, why do I need to separate components for renderItem ?

Look up "rules of hooks", they have to be at the root level of a function component.

I think it would be easier and a lot more performant to use a masked view with an opacity gradient over the top of your component (react-native-masked-view & react-native-linear-gradient)

well, I found the solution
I just needed to separate the renderItem component to separate component and use the index instead of activeNumber
That's it
Wheel Component :
import { StyleSheet, View, Modal } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import Text, { TextProps } from "../../atoms/Text";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useSharedValue,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Button from "../../atoms/Button";
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { COLORS, DEVICE } from "../../../common";
import RenderItem from "./RenderItem";

type PropsType = {
  data: { lable: string; value: string }[];
  onSelect: (value: PropsType["data"][0]) => void;
  isVisible: boolean;
  title: TextProps["tx"];
};
const SHOW_ITEMS = 5;
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 60;
const WHEEL_HEIGHT = ITEM_HEIGHT * SHOW_ITEMS;
const ITEM_WIDTH = 100;

const WheelModal = ({ onSelect, data, isVisible, title }: PropsType) => {
  const { bottom } = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const eventY = useSharedValue(0);

  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
    eventY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
  });

  const _onSelect = () => {
    const SelectedItem = data[eventY.value / ITEM_HEIGHT];
    onSelect(SelectedItem);
  };

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={isVisible} animationType="fade">
      <View style={styles.titleBox}>
        <Text weight="bold" size="lg" tx={title} />
      </View>
      <LinearGradient
        locations={[0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1]}
        colors={[
          "rgba(256,256,256,.6)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.95)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,1)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.7)",
          "rgba(256,256,256,.2)",
        ]}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
        <Animated.FlatList
          bounces={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
          onScroll={scrollHandler}
          data={data ?? []}
          decelerationRate="normal"
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          snapToInterval={ITEM_HEIGHT}
          style={styles.flatList}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={(props) => <RenderItem eventY={eventY} {...props} />}
        />
        <View style={styles.borderView} />
      </LinearGradient>
      <Button
        onPress={_onSelect}
        tx="Select"
        style={[styles.selectButton, { height: 50 + bottom }]}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradient: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  titleBox: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: DEVICE.height / 2 - WHEEL_HEIGHT / 2 - 49,
    alignSelf: "center",
    zIndex: 999,
  },
  flatList: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    height: WHEEL_HEIGHT,
  },
  flatListContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingVertical: ITEM_HEIGHT * Math.floor(SHOW_ITEMS / 2),
  },

  borderView: {
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    position: "absolute",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: COLORS.primary,
    zIndex: -1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    top: DEVICE.height / 2 - ITEM_HEIGHT / 2,
  },
  selectButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

export default WheelModal;

RenderItem Component
  import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Animated, {
  Extrapolation,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedStyle,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Text from "../../atoms/Text";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 60;
const ITEM_WIDTH = 100;
const RenderItem = ({ item, index, eventY }) => {
  const inputRange = [
    (index - 2) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    (index - 1) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    index * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    (index + 1) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
    (index + 2) * ITEM_HEIGHT,
  ];

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const opacity = interpolate(
      eventY.value,
      inputRange,
      [0.1, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.1],
      Extrapolation.CLAMP
    );
    return {
      opacity,
    };
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.animatedView, animatedStyle]}>
      <Text size="lg" weight="medium" text={item.toString()} />
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default RenderItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  animatedView: {
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

